# Modulus of Infinite Product

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, infinite-product, several-complex-variables, entire-functions

We know that for complex (entire) functions $f,g$ we have  $|f(z)g(z)|=|f(z)||g(z)|$, where $|.|$ means complex modulus.

What about if we have an infinite product? Is it true that
$$\bigg| \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} f_{k}(z)\bigg|= \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} |f_{k}(z)| $$
where $\{f_{k}\}$ is any set of entire functions. WHAT IF $f_k$ IS CONVERGENT?

Answer (score 2):

Your notation higly implies that the sequence is index by $\Bbb N$ and I'll adhere to that. The statement is true for the values of $z$ such that the product without modulus either diverges to $0$ or converges, because pointwise $\left\lvert \prod_{k=1}^n a_k\right\rvert=\prod_{k=1}^n\left\lvert  a_k\right\rvert$ for all $n$ and $\lvert \bullet\rvert$ is continuous.

Comment: Is it true if n goes to infinity?

Comment: Is the result true if $f_k $ is convergent? Or do i need some thing more??

Comment: So the statement is true if product without modulus converges. How to prove this?

Comment: Please reply. I will give you a check mark.

Answer (score 1):

I think is false, correct me if I am wrong but I think the left side can be not defined while the right side is. Consider $$f_n(z)=(-1)^n,$$ then $\Pi f_n(z)$ is not defined therefore  $|\Pi f_n(z)|$ isn't either, and in the right side is easy to see that $\Pi |f_n(z)|$ is defined and its value is $1$.

Comment: $\Pi f_n(z)$ is 1 or -1 so $|\Pi f_n(z)|$ is 1

Comment: @Shreyaanand This statement of yours statement is false by the fact that the negation of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)= 1$ is provably true and the negation of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)=-1$ is provably true.

Comment: @Shreyaanand That would be true if the product was finite, if you consider the infinite product, that is false

Comment: So this result is false?

Comment: @Shreyaanand I think you need more asumptions about $f_k$, probably something about convergence

Comment: @Gae. S. So this result is false?? What conditions should we have so that the result holds?

Comment: @J.Rodriguez what if $f_k(z)$ is convergent?

Comment: @J. Rodriguez Can you tell me the conditions

Comment: I am not sure, but if $f_k \to f$ uniformly, $f$ is entire, so maybe there the result holds

Comment: @J.Rodriguez How uniform convergence will help?

Comment: @J.Rodriguez What if$ f_k$ is convergent? Then this counter example does not works.